# Capybara-webkit command 'make' failed - Windows 8.1

Tags: ruby, git-bash, capybara-webkit

I am trying to install Capybara-webkit. I tried tutorials and guides but no luck in getting it on Windows 8.1 using Git Bash terminal.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
$ bundle exec rake build
cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile.webkit_server || c:/Qt/5.5.0/qt-5.5.0-x64-mingw510r0-seh-rev0/bin/qmake.exe C:/Users/Academy11/desktop/Ruby/webkit/capybara-webkit                                                                                                                /src/webkit_server.pro 'CONFIG\+\=test' -o Makefile.webkit_server ) && make -f M                                                                                                                akefile.webkit_server
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Academy11/desktop/Ruby/webkit/capybara-webkit/src'
make -f Makefile.webkit_server.Debug
make[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Academy11/desktop/Ruby/webkit/capybara-webkit/src'
g++ -x c++-header -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_WEBKITWIDGETS_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -IC:/Qt/5.5.0/qt-5.5.0-x64-mingw510r0-seh-rev0/include -IC:/Qt/5.5.0/qt-5.5.0-x64-mingw510r0-seh-rev0/include/QtWebKitWidgets -IC:/Qt/5.5.0/qt-5.5.0-x64-mingw510r0-seh-rev0/include/QtWidgets -IC:/Qt/5.5.0/qt-5.5.0-x64-mingw510r0-seh-rev0/include/QtWebKit -IC:/Qt/5.5.0/qt-5.5.0-x64-mingw510r0-seh-rev0/include/QtGui -IC:/Qt/5.5.0/qt-5.5.0-x64-mingw510r0-seh-rev0/include/QtANGLE -IC:/Qt/5.5.0/qt-5.5.0-x64-mingw510r0-seh-rev0/include/QtNetwork -IC:/Qt/5.5.0/qt-5.5.0-x64-mingw510r0-seh-rev0/include/QtCore -Ibuild -IC:/Qt/5.5.0/qt-5.5.0-x64-mingw510r0-seh-rev0/mkspecs/win32-g++  -o build/stable.h.gch/c++ stable.h
make[2]: g++: Command not found
make[2]: *** [build/stable.h.gch/c++] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Academy11/desktop/Ruby/webkit/capybara-webkit/src'
make[1]: *** [debug] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Academy11/desktop/Ruby/webkit/capybara-webkit/src'
make: *** [sub-src-webkit_server-pro-make_first-ordered] Error 2
Command 'make' failed
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: did you installed `qt`? https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit

Comment: Yeah followed and tried that tutorial couple of times but no success at the bottom in the Windows section

Comment: And I can't get past that step of the tutorial: $ bundle exec rake build. which is where everything goes wrong

Comment: do you have `g++` installed?

Comment: yeah I am sure I have it...How do I check if I have it to confirm in git bash?

Comment: just type `gcc`and see what it says

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review your posting. Is it easily readable? Readability makes it easier for us to help you, encouraging and speeding responses. Formatting of questions and answers is easy and well documented. Please take the time in the future to help us help you.

Comment: "`g++: Command not found`" is significant.

Comment: In this situation how would I get g++, because I think I have it considered in the tutorial by following this step:
`In QT_INSTALL_DIR\4.8.5\mkspecs\win32-g++\qmake.conf)
# Ex: C:\Qt\4.8.5\mkspecs\win32-g++\qmake.conf
# Add the following after the line beginning with QMAKE_IDC
QMAKE_RCC = $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]$${DIR_SEPARATOR}rcc$${EXE_SUFFIX}
QMAKE_LFLAGS = -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++`